# Fastest method of searching and removing elements from a sorted vector of integers in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, sorting

I have a large vector of sorted integers. I need to quickly find and remove eight values from the array.

For example, vector a includes the elements

```
{1, 4, 7, 15, 16, 19, 24, 26, 31, 53, 67, 68, 73, 75, 77, 82}
```

vector b includes the eight values

```
{4, 15, 19, 24, 67, 68, 73, 75}
```

After completing the operation, vector a should now have

```
{1, 7, 16, 26, 31, 53, 77, 82}
```

My old solution was pretty slow:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator val = b.begin(); val != b.end(); val++)
        a.erase(remove(a.begin(), a.end(), *val), a.end());
```

Is there a faster method?

EDIT:

Actually, my "A" vector is a lot larger than my "B" vector. Maybe it's better to just search for the individual elements via a binary search and delete them?

EDIT2:

Perhaps a vector isn't a good container for this kind of operation. I don't think I can use forward_list because I cannot compile with C++11. Maybe I can use a different container and then copy the results into a vector afterwards?

Comment: you can use binary search to find elements, but do you have to use vector ? it's not the best choice for removing elements.

Comment: @mohaned For performance, it actually might be, see http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style

Comment: Yes, I need to use a vector. Also, I can't use C++11.

Comment: I thing best way to search sorted vector is binary search `O(lg(n))` so you can repeat it for the 8 values and delete your elements , @BaummitAugen I will read it soon.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, I just realized that remove() doesn't use a binary search. I'll look up binary search algorithm in the stl.

Comment: If you can use std::forward_list instead of std::vector, there will be much less overhead removing elements.

Comment: @mohaned - While the search is O(lg(n)), the remove is not, and this is where the time will be spent.

Comment: @Logicrat That is most likely a [really bad idea](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style).

Comment: @AnimatedRNG - Pls see the edit to mine explaining details on O(complexity) and comparing it to your original solution and edits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would probably do something like:

```
std::vector<int> temp;

std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), 
                    b.begin(), b.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(temp));
std::swap(a, temp);
```

Edit based on edited question:

Given that your `a` vector is substantially larger than your `b` vector, there's a second question I'd consider: do you need `a` to remain sorted after this is complete?

If rearranging elements in `a` is allowed, then you can improve speed substantially: instead of doing a remove/erase to remove the items from the middle of `a`, you can swap the item to be removed with the last element of `a`, then erase it from the end (which has constant complexity). This makes the removals constant, so the overall complexity is O(N log M) (where N = b.size() and M = a.size()).

If you do have to maintain order, you can still improve speed somewhat: instead of removing elements from `a`, then immediately erasing the removed element, do an `std::remove_if` to find all the elements of `a` that need to be removed, then once (when that's done) do one erase to remove all those elements.

As it stands right now, you're using a separate call to `remove` for each element of `a` that you remove. All the elements of `a` after each removal point are copied (or moved, if applicable) for each `remove`. That means if you remove 10 elements from `a`, you're copying (on average) half of `a` 10 times over. By using a single `remove_if` instead, you're copying each element of `a` only once.

Unfortunately, `remove_if` doesn't give you a good way to take advantage of the ordering in `b`. You can use a binary search, which helps some, but not as much as you'd like.

If you don't mind writing your own loop, you can take full advantage of the fact that both `a` and `b` are sorted, something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Compute the difference between two "set"s in-place. Each 'set' must be a
// sorted sequence.
//
template <class FwdIt, class InIt>
FwdIt 
inplace_set_difference(FwdIt b1, FwdIt e1, InIt b2, InIt e2) {
    FwdIt pos = b1;
    while (pos != e1 && b2 != e2) {
        if (*pos < *b2)
            *b1++ = *pos++;
        else if (*b2 < *pos)
            ++b2;
        else
            ++pos;
    }
    while (pos != e1)
        *b1++ = *pos++;
    return b1;
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
    std::vector<int> b{ 2, 5, 9 };

    auto it = inplace_set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    a.erase(it, a.end());

    for (auto i : a)
        std::cout << i << '\t';
}
```

If you wanted to make this maximally generic, you'd probably want to change it to only use post-increment on the iterators, allow the user to pass a comparison operator instead of using `<` directly, etc. These are left as the dreaded "exercise for the reader".

It's probably worth noting that this is basically the same algorithm as `set_difference` normally uses, just with minor adjustment to operate in-place. This does cause a substantial change in the interface though: since it can (and does) create duplicate elements in the collection, it can be applied to a sorted sequence (vector, deque, hash, etc.) but *not* to an associative container (`[unordered_][multi_](set|map)`).

Since this traverses `a` and `b` exactly once each, it's clearly `O(N + M)`, but since we're starting with the idea that `M`(=b.size()) is small, it's effectively `O(N)`

Note: the test code uses C++11 features heavily (e.g., to initialize the two vectors) but I believe the algorithm implementation itself should be fine in C++98/03.

Comment: This method works really well if A and B are of roughly the same magnitude (it runs in O(n) time ignoring removal). However, if B is very small (like my example of 8 elements), it's better to do a binary search for every element, which would be O(k*log(n) ignoring removal) where k is the size of B.

Comment: @AnimatedRNG: There could be special cases that would favor doing doing a binary search for each element of `b` and removing it individually. Mostly those would involve knowing not only that `b` is small, but that the elements of `b` are close to the end of `a`. The methods I've given run in O(N) *including* removal. In general, doing an individual binary search for each element of B in A, then removing that element will be `O(N M log N)` (where N=a.size() and M=b.size()).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing elements, just add items to a new vector. Assuming your inputs are 'original' (A) and 'toRemove' (B), just create iterators for both original and toRemove:

If the next item in original matches the next item in toRemove, drop it. Otherwise, copy it to the result. 
If it's greater than the next item in toRemove, go to the next item in toRemove and run the comparison again.

This way, you're only iterating over each list once, and not constantly copying array values around during a 'remove' operation.

This solution will run in O(A+B), which is faster than your current (and proposed) solution.

For comparison purposes: 
Your existing solution which is roughly O(A*A*B) (A for remove, A for non-optimized search, B for iterating over B).
Your edit suggests doing a binary search to remove the elements; this will only improve your original solution to O(logA*A*B) (A for remove, logA for optimized search, B for iterating over B).

Comment: Great, that runs in O(n) time!

Comment: See my comment on Jerry Coffin's post

Answer (score -1):

Built in functions in the vector header are faster. For example,

> vector  vect;

and after adding all the elements, you could use

> sort(vect.begin(),vect.end());

That would sort the list in ascending order. For descending, you might have to perform

> reverse(vect.begin,vect.end());

on the **Sorted List**.

Comment: Your first code snippet won't compile and if you want a descending sort you'd pass an appropriate comparison function object to `std::sort`. None of this "answer" applies to the posted question.

Comment: The first sentence is also bollocks; <algorithm> functions are not slower. And the last sentence doesn't make sense because a std::vector is not a std::list. The few parts of the question which aren't outright wrong are indeed irrelevant.